# Removed PHC on enp

Tags: ifconfig, dmesg

Why is the PHC is removed on my ethernet interface? Is that the reason why I couldn't see the interface in ifconfig? I have inserted the 10Gbe cable and I can clearly see it is connected.

Output of `dmesg | grep -e ixgbe -e enp`:

[image]